# Why would a truthy check on an enum value not work like I expect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, enums, truthiness

On my `membership` model, I have the following enum value:

```
enum relative_type: { member: 0, user: 1 }
```

Then elsewhere in some code, when it comes upon a `membership` model, I have this `if-branch`

```
      if membership.user?
        member = Member.create(first_name: self.first_name, last_name: self.last_name, email: self.email, bio: self.bio, gender: self.gender, avatar: self.avatar, birthday: self.birthday, deceased: false)
        membership.update!(member: member, invited: nil, relative_type: 0)
        binding.pry
        membership.inviter_connection.update!(request_status: 3)
      end
```

The weird thing is for attributes where `membership.user?` returns `false`, execution still gets passed inside the `if` block.

Here is an example of the a `pry` session.

```
    207:           if membership.user?
    208:             member = Member.create(first_name: self.first_name, last_name: self.last_name, email: self.email, bio: self.bio, gender: self.gender, avatar: self.avatar, birthday: self.birthday, deceased: false)
    209:             membership.update!(member: member, invited: nil, relative_type: 0)
 => 210:             binding.pry
    211:             membership.inviter_connection.update!(request_status: 3)
    212:           end
    213:         end
    214:       else
    215: 

[1] pry(#<User>)> membership.user?
=> false
[2] pry(#<User>)> membership
=> #<Membership id: 11045, family_tree_id: 76631, user_id: 31643, created_at: "2016-02-06 08:16:54", updated_at: "2016-02-06 08:18:08", relation: "brother", member_id: 9872, invited_id: nil, relative_type: 0>
[3] pry(#<User>)> membership.relative_type
=> "member"
[4] pry(#<User>)> membership.member?
=> true
```

So from the `membership` object above, you can see that the `membership.relative_type` is equal to `0`, which corresponds to `member`. So that works like you would expect, particularly given that `membership.member?` returns true.

What I don't understand is....in this current instance, why on earth is this instance of PRY being executed from within the `if` block that should only be executed if `membership.user?` is true....yet is clearly false here.

**Edit 1**

The weird thing is that I edited the method to be more explicit, like so:

`if membership.user? == true`

But it still sends the execution into the `if-block` even when `membership.user?` is false.

```
    207:           if membership.user? == true
    208:             member = Member.create(first_name: self.first_name, last_name: self.last_name, email: self.email, bio: self.bio, gender: self.gender, avatar: self.avatar, birthday: self.birthday, deceased: false)
    209:             membership.update!(member: member, invited: nil, relative_type: 0)
 => 210:             binding.pry
    211:             membership.inviter_connection.update!(request_status: 3)
    212:           end
    213:         end
    214:       else
    215: 

[1] pry(#<User>)> membership.user?
=> false
[2] pry(#<User>)> membership.user?
=> false
[3] pry(#<User>)> membership.member?
=> true
```

**Edit 2**

I even took it a step further and compared the actual values of the enum, like so:

```
    207:           if membership.relative_type == 'user'
    208:             member = Member.create(first_name: self.first_name, last_name: self.last_name, email: self.email, bio: self.bio, gender: self.gender, avatar: self.avatar, birthday: self.birthday, deceased: false)
    209:             membership.update!(member: member, invited: nil, relative_type: 0)
 => 210:             binding.pry
    211:             membership.inviter_connection.update!(request_status: 3)
    212:           end
    213:         end
    214:       else
    215: 

[1] pry(#<User>)> membership
=> #<Membership id: 11049, family_tree_id: 76639, user_id: 31647, created_at: "2016-02-06 08:41:59", updated_at: "2016-02-06 08:42:02", relation: "brother", member_id: 9874, invited_id: nil, relative_type: 0>
[2] pry(#<User>)> membership.relative_type
=> "member"
```

But still no dice.

Comment: Well. can you add binding before the `if` and check the return value? Because, inside the `if` block, you are updating the enum value and you are inspecting there... Also show the schema of the table.

Comment: oooohhh.... @ArupRakshit, you are a genius. DUH. The line right before the `binding.pry` at 210 updates the `membership` record and changes the `relative_type`. That's why it keeps giving me `membership.user? => false` within the block. It was true at the beginning of the block.

Comment: because you have updated it here `membership.update!(member: member, invited: nil, relative_type: 0)` with a new version of type